# Android - Algorithm for remembering already processed photos

Tags: opencv, image-processing, android-canvas, android

I have an Android app which lets the user process some photos, adding filters.
One of them is to add a datestamp to the photo, which can have only the date or both date and time.

What I need to do is, given a photo as input, even if that photo has been compressed, for example, in order to be sent through a messaging app, determine if that image has been datestamped previously or not.

Of course, I'm not asking about a complete implementation, but about a few ideas.

Right now I thought about marking some pixels of the image and then, by using HSV, try to find a similar color to the one initially set in that position.

Another approach I thought about was to try to locate the text, but my problem is that the possible positions are the four corners of the image (user chooses), and the color can be one of 27 different colors, so I cannot search for yellow on the lower-right corner of the image. 
But, anyway, any idea about how to locate the date if it was always yellow and located on the lower-right corner are welcome.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: so you want to detect only the ones your app has modified?

Comment: @muratgu Yes. Only the ones my app has modified, but they could be modified on another device and then transferred via a messaging app, so I cannot rely only on DBs or EXIF data

Comment: it would be over-engineering, but one could train an opencv image recognizer. I don't know exactly how.